# What MTA to use to deliver locally-generated mail only on debian?

Tags: debian, mail-transport-agent

Basically what i'm looking for

- Locally generated mail to local users is forwarded to some outside address
- Locally generated mail to remote domains is sent out directly to their MX servers (no smarthost)
- Doesn't ever receive mail over SMTP from remote systems
- Doesn't ever delivers anything locally
- Minimal configuration and fiddling needed

I've looked at ssmtp and nullmailer and both seem simple enough to set up but they need a smarthost which i don't have. All the other MTAs in debian seem to be way over the top for what i need and need a lot of complicated setup.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of Debian's standard configuration packages such as `exim4` or `postfix`. (I think the default is now `postfix` but it certainly used to be `exim4`.) During installation you'll be asked for the scenario you require, and one of the options will either match you requirements or get very close:

- "Locally generated mail to local users is forwarded to some outside address" - local delivery with `/etc/aliases` to redirect offsite
- "Locally generated mail to remote domains is sent out directly to their MX servers (no smarthost)" - remote (off-site) delivery
- "Doesn't ever receive mail over SMTP from remote systems" - no inbound acceptance
- "Doesn't ever delivers anything locally" - see your first point
- "Minimal configuration and fiddling needed" - the package provides a standard configuration option to cover these use cases